# Unicode, _stprintf() and mixed text directions

Tags: c++, winapi, unicode, printf, bidi

I'm working on refactoring some legacy c++ code to support Unicode and I am experiencing problems when a _stprintf is used with a format string of _T("%s %s") and the arguments are: arabic text(right-to-left) followed by some digits stored in a character array. Here is a code snippet:

```
auto buf = std::make_unique<TCHAR>();
TCHAR Text[]{_T("حبيبيحبيبيحبيب")};
TCHAR Number[]{_T("12345678h90")};

_stprintf(buf.get(), _T("%s %s"), Text, Number);
```

What I get in buf is حبيبيحبيبيحبيب 12345678h90, but what I want to get is the contents of the Text array followed by the contents of the Number array. (I tried to paste it here but it got automatically formated in the same way as the _stprintf does it...).

I know that the reason for this is that arabic text is a strong character type and all of the numbers are weak types and I have a relatively simple solution - overload _stprintf , check if a parameter string begins with digits and prepend the U+200E (\u200E) control character. However, I can't help but think that there might be a simpler solution that I don't know about like a global setting or something?  Is there something like that?

These strings that are being passed to SetWindowText and are displayed in the wrong order because of the arabic. My main goal is to get them to render properly in the UI.

Comment: Why can't you use the format string of `_T("%s\x200E %s")` always? It will simply guarantee that the second (Number) field is to the right of the first (Text) field, no matter whether the Text is RTL. BTW, your buffer is ordered exactly as you expect it to be ordered. It is only rendered this way.

Comment: I don't really want to change the format string, because it would mean going through all of the _stprintf calls in the code(there are around 10k of them). The last part of your comment was really helpful though! These strings that are being passed to SetWindowText and are displayed in the wrong order because of the arabic. My main goal is to get them to render properly in the UI. Any clue how I can do that?

Comment: What would be the universal "properly" for render of around 10000 different formatted strings some of which may or may not contain pieces of Arabic text? The output you have now is the result of Windows' best effort to render this text on a meaningful way. You need a very clear spec to deliver something robustly better. Maybe, only few format strings should be modified?

Comment: By the time you pass the string to Windows, the fact that it was originally two strings glued together is lost. Windows displays the string according to the Unicode Bidirectional Algorithm, and the Unicode bidirectional algorithm places the digits on visual left because digits have weak directionality. If you want it to display some other way, you need to adjust the string that you're passing in. Not sure what other solution you're looking for.